# Do sub classes need to implement Interfaces?

Tags: class, inheritance, interface

This is more of an understanding question.I have an Interface called InterExe1 and it has 2 methods-print1(), print2().
This interface is implemented by a super class-Worker

```
 public class Worker implements InterExe1
```

and then I also have 2 subclasses inheriting from the Worker class and also implementing the interface

```
Public class DayWorker extends Worker implements InterExe1
Public class nightWorker extends Worker implements InterExe1
```

If the interface is already implemented through the super class do I need to implement it individually through the subclasses as well because I wrote they implement it? I'm not sure because technically they inherit all methods in Worker and Worker implements the Interface, Does it actually make a difference if I wrote in the subclasses that they implement the interface or not what is the difference if I didnt write it? I tried to make these classes and when I didn't implement the Worker class it showed an error-compile error before running it and but it still didn't require me to implement the subclasses although they would have no implementation of the interface. Do you know why?When I did implement only the super class it showed no error  at all.I would be very grateful if you could help I have test on it today and I need to understand the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If the interface is already implemented through the super class do I need to implement it individually through the subclasses as well because I wrote they implement it?

  - No
- I'm not sure because technically they inherit all methods in Worker and Worker implements the Interface, Does it actually make a difference if I wrote in the subclasses that they implement the interface or not what is the difference if I didnt write it?

  - No. Apart from it's redundant
- I tried to make these classes and when I didn't implement the Worker class it showed an error-compile error before running it and but it still didn't require me to implement the subclasses although they would have no implementation of the interface. Do you know why?

  - If a class implements an interface, it has to implement all the methods. If you have implemented in `Worker`, your subclass inherits there methods from parent class.

To be honest, try IntelliJ Community version, you can easily see the answer.

Per Effective Java, I believe your `Worker` should be an abstract class. You will find it's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement it in the sub-class (`derived` class).

The derived class inherits all the implementations of the base class, and can override any of the virtual implementations.